# Which are the French expressions close to “Being Pissed”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, registre-familier

It's really common to use the slang “Pissed” in English. For example, “He gets pissed really fast”, “I am pissed with him” etc.

What are the common expressions equivalent of “Piss”?

Comment: "He gets pissed really fast" is ambiguous.  It could mean: #1 angry; #2 drunk.  "Pissed off" is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is all the range of words for "angry" that you can use, such as:

- Être *fâché* / Se fâcher facilement
- Être *en colère* / Se mettre en colère facilement
- Être *furieux* / Se mettre en furie facilement
- Être *énervé* / S'énerver facilement

If you want slang, you can use this:

- Être *en pétard* / Se mettre en pétard facilement

If you're in Québec, you can also use this:

- Être *en (beau) maudit* / Se mettre en maudit facilement

Comment: Bonne résponse. «S'énerver» semble assez courant pour moi, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tS4CS8y-WaY

Comment: On peut ajouter les variantes familères comme _furibard_ ou _vénèr_, ou les euphémismes comme _agacé_ ou _contrarié_ (parfois précédés de _profondément_ et dits sur un ton de colère froide).

Answer (score 8):

Let's try to give some translations in context.

- *He gets pissed really fast*, in familiar speech:

  > Il en faut pas beaucoup pour le rendre furax.
- *I am pissed with him*, in (common) vulgar slang:

  > Il me fait chier.
  >
  > Il m'emmerde.

Comment: Y s'vénèr facile.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add:

> Je suis **saoulé**.
>
> Ça (Cela) me **saoule**.

*Saoulé* meaning "drunk" [(source)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saouler).